Trying to remove an ajax action to do my own
I'm using the Forminator Plugin for Wordpress, and right now I'm trying to remove the action that (I asume) calls the default AJAX function that handles the POST, I have found this two actions:
add_action( 'wp_ajax_forminator_submit_form_' . static::$entry_type, array( $this, 'save_entry' ) );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_forminator_submit_form_' . static::$entry_type, array( $this, 'save_entry' ) );

Supposedly removing this should be ok to implement my own script, but even if a remove this actions on my functions.php like this, it won't work and the AJAX function still works and the form is submitted:
remove_action('wp_ajax_forminator_submit_form_custom-forms', array('Forminator_Front_Action','save_entry'), 12);

I need to replace this action so I can work with the POST data right after submit, but I dont' know where to add mine aswell, but most important: why it isn't removing the other action, I'll appreciate any help!

As callables, array( $this, 'save_entry' ) and array('Forminator_Front_Action','save_entry') are not the same thing. The former is binding a method of a specific class instance ($this), whereas the second one using the class name, would only work for calling a static method.
